# adb.exe hang on windows 7

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I have recently installed Android SDK with ADT from developer.android.com
it was working fine and i build the hello world app and installed it on phone using ADT. 
but after sometime when i run the project it keeps display the message ddmd post-create init
and then nothing happens. i waited a lot but it hangs on this message
i tried all the methods given like

1. delete .lock file
2. end process through task manager
3. delete .android folder
4. delete .metadata/.project folder
5. run adb kill-server and adb devices but it hangs on waiting for
   device
6. set path in environment variables
7. installed other IDE like netbeans and  intelliJ
8. deleted Android SDK and installed it on another location
9. restarted system
10. putting platform-tools files in tools folder
11. updated IDE and SDK manager

none of the above methods worked for me
whenever i run  project the ddms post-create init message appears and then nothing happens for several hours!!

please please please give me a solution. i am tired of doing the above method
i have windows 7 32bit
JDK 1.7
JRE 7
latest Android SDK and Eclipse ADT

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm working in a node module, under Windows 7 dev environment, I'm creating and deleting a Cordova project, and every time that the project is built or emulated, is not possible to delete the root folder, I've found out that adb.exe process it was locking the folder, so the solution it was quite simple, just kill the process.

This is an old problem that I'm following with the Android SDK according to several Android forums, somehow we are not the only ones with this kind of problem.

People still have this problem in different case scenarios. In my case, I came out with a non-elegant solution but, it works for me perfectly, just kill the process before remove the project folder.

Look for any way to kill the process over windows, or a way to execute a command using the console, what I did is execute this into cmd, when is required:

```
TASKKILL /F /IM ADB.exe /T
```

Like, I said before, it would better find a way to unlock the folder without kill the process.